# Using Instagram api without authentication

Tags: php, instagram-api

Is there a way to fetch images by hashtag without authentication, using the instagram API?

as far as I saw, it is not possible...

let's say using php

for example: I want to launch a cron task, which will be fetching photos by some specific hardcoded hashtag, but doing this will require the `access_token`, which as I see can be gotten only when the user manually authenticates

the question is: it is possible to use instagram api, without user interaction?

and if yes, how?

Comment: Nope. Instragram have a restrictive API and it's more difficult now than it used to be to get access to it

Comment: @NathanDawson, looks like parsing photos using curl is the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Well** Since the acquisition of instagram by facebook and [Policy Update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update) which was implemented on June 1st 2016. **"You cannot"** Officially use the API without approving your app from instagram.

Answer (score 2):

You can use library [czPechy/instagramProfileCrawler](https://github.com/czPechy/instagramProfileCrawler) for crawling profile without API.

With composer you install

```
$ composer require czpechy/instagramprofilecrawler
```

And now you can use this

```
$client = new \czPechy\instagramProfileCrawler\Client('instagramUsername');
$profile = $client->getProfile();
```

This is html crawler, but it has been working for over a year